# Linux Voice Changer (Mumble, Team Speak)

Tags: voice

It seems easy to change voice in Windows just like this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmlYiK6fgX0

Unfortunately, [Voicemod](https://www.voicemod.net/) is not available on Linux yet.

I've been searching for Linux Voice Changer and found this link

[7 Best Real Time Voice Changer for Discord Apps 2020](https://geekhax.com/best-voice-changer-for-discord/)

Out of 7 Best Real Time Voice Changer provided, only 2 supported by Linux which is [Mumble](https://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Main_Page) and [Team Speak](https://www.teamspeak.com/en/)

I've installed both apps, unfortunately, I still can't figure out how to change a voice.

Should there is any good tutorial on it, please let me know.

Comment: Please note that using a voice changer is not a good way to protect your identity from voice analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Lyrebird](https://github.com/constcharptr/lyrebird). It does practically the same thing that [@john-doe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/596311/220439) posted, but it has GTK GUI.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a much better way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421947/is-there-a-way-to-modulate-my-voice-on-the-fly) . I would also state that any voice modifier is easy to bypass and get the original voice, and you can be fingerprinted by the way you speak regardless if there is a voice modifier. It is far from foolproof I can assure you.